# How do I have bixby use app-launch to open google maps?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to open google maps using the on-click key from a compound card, but I don't know what to include in the payload-URI key for app-launch. The documentation uses the example which is commented out, but I do not know what to fill in for the application(google-maps).

I am getting two errors both being Unknown key `message/app-launch`.

This is the code we are trying to use, so that when a compound card is clicked, it opens google maps with app-launch.

```
// PersonSelectionView.view.bxb
input-view {
  match: Spot (this)

  // optional selection dialog to overwrite any other default dialog
  message (Pick a spot)

  render {
    // used to iterate over the list of candidates
    selection-of (this) {
      navigation-mode {
        read-none {
          list-summary ("There are #{size(this)} #{value(categories)} spots near you")
          item-selection-question (Which one would you like?)
        }
      }
      where-each (one) {
        // you can use conditional logic to control how candidates are displayed,
        // using either a standard layout with a match pattern, or a layout macro
        compound-card {
          content {
            map-card {
              title-area {
                slot1 {
                  text {
                    value("#{value (one.spotName)}")
                  }
                }
                slot3 {
                  single-line {
                    text {
                      value("#{value (one.distance)} Miles away")
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              aspect-ratio (1:1)
              markers {
                marker {
                  geo ("Location.point")
                  icon {
                    template (/images/icons/red-marker.png)
                  }
                  width (15)
                  height (20)
                  anchor-x (5)
                  anchor-y (15)
                  rotation (0)
                }
              }
            }
            paragraph {
              value {
                template ("#{raw(description)}")
              }
              style (Detail_L)
            }
          }
          on-click {
            message ("TESTING THIS MESSAGE")
            app-launch {
              //payload-uri ("bixby://com.android.systemui/DummySystem/punchOut")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An "Unknown Key" error means that the key you are trying to define is not one of the valid child keys of the key you are currently in. The [reference section](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference) of the [Bixby Developer Documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/) provides each key with its valid child keys.

Both `app-launch` and `message` are not child keys of `on-click`.

- `app-launch` cannot be defined within an `on-click`. It must be defined in its own `result-view`.
- `message` can be defined in multiple keys but not `on-click`

Your `on-click` would need to redirect to a separate `result-view` which would contain the `app-launch` key with the correct `payload-uri` defined.

You would need the following to implement the behavior you described:

- An Action (and backing Action Javascript) to return the URI
- A Concept to hold the URI returned by the Action
- A `result-view` with a `match` that matches the Concept

Example Action:

```
action (LaunchDefinedUri) {
  description (Launches the defined uri)
  type (Commit)
  collect {
    input (launchUri) {
      type (LaunchUri)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (LaunchUri)
}
```

Example Action Javascript:

```
module.exports = {
  function: LaunchDefinedUri
}

function LaunchDefinedUri(launchUri) {
  return launchUri
}
```

Example Concept:

```
text (LaunchUri) {
  description (Uri to be launched)
}
```

Example Result View:

```
result-view {
  match: LaunchUri(this)

  app-launch {
    payload-uri("#{value(this)}")
  }

  render {
    nothing
  }
}
```

As for Google Maps API in particular, the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) seems to provide information on how to define the correct URIs for your specific purpose and behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into this official library provided by the Bixby team, which provides punch-out to Google Maps.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.navigation